# Nested quotes have smaller and smaller paragraph skips

Tags: spacing, memoir, paragraphs, quoting, parskip

I'm using Memoir and `\abnormalparskip{<length>}`.

Every time I start a new `\begin{quote}`, the space between paragraphs gets smaller and smaller until it's basically gone.

Here is a minimal test case:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\abnormalparskip{1em}

\begin{document}

This is a a normal paragraph. It will space correctly from the next.

This is the second paragraph to show how it is spaced correctly.

\begin{quote}

  This is the first paragraph in a quote. It is not spaced right.

  This paragraph is spaced smaller than the one before it.

  \begin{quote}

    This is yet another paragraph.

    Now you can see the spacing is gone.

  \end{quote}

\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

Which results in this:

[image: results]

How do get it so that the paragraph skip is consistently the same size?

Comment: That's by design. quote is a list, and nested lists have smaller \parsep (which is used as \parskip in the list). You would have to redefine the `\@listi`, `\@listii` etc commands to change this. Or reset \parskip inside the quote enviroment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **Ulrike Fischer** mentions in [her comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250809/nested-quotes-have-smaller-and-smaller-paragraph-skips/250811#comment597521_250809), one option is to change `\parskip` inside the list internally used by `quote`; for consistency's sake, the same modification will be required for the quotation environment. The following example code shows the necessary redefinitions:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\newlength\myparskip
\setlength\myparskip{1em}
\abnormalparskip{\myparskip}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{quote}%
  {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
  \parskip=\myparskip\item[]}%
  {\endlist}
\renewenvironment{quotation}%
  {\list{}{\listparindent 1.5em%
    \itemindent    \listparindent
    \rightmargin   \leftmargin
    \parsep        \z@ \@plus\p@}%
    \parskip=\myparskip\item[]}%
  {\endlist}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

This is a a normal paragraph. It will space correctly from the next.

This is the second paragraph to show how it is spaced correctly.

\begin{quote}

  This is the first paragraph in a quote. It will space correctly from the next.

  This is the second paragraph to show how it is spaced correctly.

  \begin{quote}

    This is another paragraph in a quote. It will space correctly from the next.

    This is the second paragraph to show how it is spaced correctly.

    \begin{quote}

      This is yet another paragraph in a quote. It will space correctly from the next.

      This is the second paragraph to show how it is spaced correctly.

    \end{quote}
  \end{quote}
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As it can be deduced from the name given to `\abnormalparskip`, the author of the `memoir` class doesn't like documents with a nonzero `\parskip`. And I heartily agree with him.

If you want your document to be as ugly as possible (and possibly uglier), here's how you can do.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\abnormalparskip{1em}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\list}[2]{%
  \ifnum \@listdepth >5\relax
    \@toodeep
  \else
    \global\advance\@listdepth\@ne
  \fi
  \rightmargin\z@
  \listparindent\everylistparindent
  \itemindent\z@
  \csname @list\romannumeral\the\@listdepth\endcsname
  \def\@itemlabel{#1}%
  \let\makelabel\@mklab
  \@nmbrlistfalse
  #2\relax
  \@trivlist
  \ifm@mnzpskip
    \parsep=\parskip
  \else
    \parskip\parsep
  \fi
  \parindent\listparindent
  \advance\linewidth -\rightmargin
  \advance\linewidth -\leftmargin
  \advance\@totalleftmargin \leftmargin
  \parshape \@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
  \ignorespaces}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

This is a a normal paragraph. It will space correctly from the next.

This is the second paragraph to show how it is spaced correctly.

\begin{quote}

  This is the first paragraph in a quote. It is not spaced right.

  This paragraph is spaced smaller than the one before it.

  \begin{quote}

    This is yet another paragraph.

    Now you can see the spacing is gone.

  \end{quote}

\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of fully copying the definition of `\list` and modifying it, a quicker patch is possible.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\abnormalparskip{1em}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\list}
 {\parskip\parsep}
 {\ifm@mnzpskip\parsep\parskip\else\parskip\parsep\fi}
 {}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

This is a a normal paragraph. It will space correctly from the next.

This is the second paragraph to show how it is spaced correctly.

\begin{quote}

  This is the first paragraph in a quote. It is not spaced right.

  This paragraph is spaced smaller than the one before it.

  \begin{quote}

    This is yet another paragraph.

    Now you can see the spacing is gone.

  \end{quote}

\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've read the documentation on \abnormalparskip and while I agree in most contexts, it works well in my current context. That said, your solution seems not as clean as the other one here.

Comment: @sdegutis To the contrary: it preserves the `\parskip` in *every* environment based on `\list`, not just `quote` or `quotation`.

Comment: Oh that's neat. Although I only use quote.

Comment: I like your patch, it seems cleaner.